# detect.tflite v1 oloosing confidence for same object ( Python )

Tags: python, object-detection, tensorflow-lite

Im making a object detection using `detect.tflite` version1.
my code is consuming frames from a camera.

its working fine.

my problem is in the confidence for detected object. some time whem my object stays on the frame the % of confidence drops from 73% to 22% for same object.

what can causes it ?

im trying to compile the object detection v2 to tflite but i cant do that. it always generate error.
some one have tflite v2 version for objects detetions?
or how can i improve the confidence for my actual detetcion?

Comment: I'm not clear on what model you're using. Maybe link to it and also mention what dataset the model is trained on and what object you're trying to detect. Also mention if the confidence drops with the image in the same location/distance/lighting/blur vs the image being different in some way. Is 73% detection score the best you're seeing?

Comment: its trained with coco 2017 dataset. i got pre trained model from tensorflow litle site.